# OCR-A Font With FPDF does not work for BOLD style

Tags: fonts, fpdf, ocra

I created OCRA.PHP and OCRA.z for OCR-A Font  online and used with below code

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('OCRA','','OCRA.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('OCRA','',35);
$pdf->Write(10,'Enjoy new fonts with FPDF!');
$pdf->Output();
```

But when i add style 'B' bold it does not work

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
$pdf->AddFont('OCRA','','OCRA.php');
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('OCRA','B',20); // added 'B' - bold here
$pdf->Write(10,'Enjoy new fonts with FPDF!');
$pdf->Output();
```

It throws error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'FPDF error: Undefined font: ocra B'

Please help me to figureout the issue. Thanks

Comment: Note that your title doesn't match what you have in the body, specifically you're failing with orca B, not A - see linked question or Google /that/ font & "bold"

Comment: Thanks @Gwyn Evans I got idea from your comments. I know how to fix now.